# Accessing Knockout.js viewmodel properties in javascript

Tags: knockout.js

I have following viewModel:

```
var ViewModel = function (myList) {
    var self = this;

    this.sName = ko.observable($('#s-input').select(0).val());
};
```

I want to access the value stored in sName to do some validations:

on submit i call a validation function which checks whether the property is set to some specific value. But I am unable to access the property sName. [Documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html) says we can access the value by saying

```
ViewModel.sName()
```

I could not get it working. I tried     ViewModel.sName(),     ViewModel().sName() etc.

Anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be more explanation than you need, but it looks like you are confusing an object definition with an object. The code you posted defines a `function`, not an `object`. Note the first line:

```
var ViewModel = function (myList) { ...
```

Here you are essentially defining a javascript "class" (javascript doesn't really have classes, but its useful terminology). We call this definition a `constructor`, because it constructs objects of that type when we call it. You still need to *instantiate* that type into an object before you can use it like an object.

RP Niemeyer was showing you how to do this. Because your `constructor` takes a `myList` parameter, RP passed in a list. Generally, you will supply this list from the server as initial data in your viewmodel. In your specific case, you don't appear to be using it, so you can leave it out.

One thing you might consider is passing in the jQuery selector you are using as a parameter, so that it can be reused. That would look like this:

```
var ViewModel = function (selector) {
    var self = this;

    self.sName = ko.observable($(selector).select(0).val());
};
var vm = new ViewModel('#s-input');
var name = vm.sName(); //This is your name property!!
```

Answer (score 2):

The structure that you created is a constructor function.

You would need to create an instance of your `ViewModel` by doing something like:

```
var vm = new ViewModel(list);
```

Then, you would do `vm.sName()` to access the observable's value;

Comment: I am sorry, but I did not understand what you are pointing at.. where do i get list from? If I have to create an object, then i need to refer the old constructor function.

Comment: @Amit, do you understand the code that you posted in your question? You have created a constructor function, named `ViewModel`, which takes a paramater that you named `myList`. RP was just giving you an example of how to use your own code.